Allow Insecure Local Content in Vscode Markdown Preview?
Does anyone know a way to permanently enable Insecure Local Content in Vscode Markdown Preview? I am currently using Joplin with Vscode (via the plugin) and I work with a lot of markdown files that with attachments (e.g. screenshots). The screenshots are disabled by default by markdown preview and I need to allow insecure content for each markdown file that's edited. I did not see any security settings that I could tweak in settings.json other than:
"security.promptForLocalFileProtocolHandling": false,
"security.restrictUNCAccess": false
But these did not seem to do the trick.. does anyone know a workaround?
